# how to add a box containing text (mean=....,sigma=...) in the left side and a horizontally laied histogramm in the right side of a plot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

My code is very straighforaward.i want to plot some columns againt each other from mpg dataset.But i wan to to add a box containing text (mean=....,sigma=...) in the left side and a horizontally laied histogramm in the right side of a plot .Of course the histogramm and the text are of the data used as y-axis.Here the simple of the plot witout hist and text box:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot2:: ggplot(data = mpg)+aes_string(x="displ",y= "hwy") +geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear how your final plot should look like. But one option would be to create three separate plots and glue them together using e.g. `patchwork`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(data = mpg, aes(y = hwy)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 2) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(mpg$hwy))

p3 <- ggplot(mpg) +
  theme_void() +
  annotate(
    geom = "label",
    x = 0, y = .5,
    label = paste0(
      "mean = ", round(mean(mpg$hwy), 1), "\n",
      "sigma = ", round(sd(mpg$hwy), 1)
    ),
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))

p3 + p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1, 3, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!!!. is there any other possible method  without ptachwork .I mean directly with ggplot2. is it possible to add two horizontal red lines on the plot and highlight (with red colors for ex) the points above and under those lines?